# How to view a section cut with MeshLab

Tags: meshlab

I have seen MeshLab screenshots in which the mesh is viewed by a section/cut. I wonder how I can do that by MeshLab:

[image: A cut/section is viewed]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick answer:

- ctrl+wheel move the front clipping plane back and forth (on mac command+wheel)

Remember that there is a quick onscreen help with a summary of the various shortcuts working on the 3D window and in the layer window:

[image]